# Laravel error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found for multi authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I want to make use of multiple authentication in my LoginController, I have the following code (reduced for brevity)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller{

use AuthenticatesUsers;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    $this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');
}

public function showAdminLoginForm()
{
    return view('auth.login', ['url' => 'admin']);
}

public function adminLogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

  -->  if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {
 
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
}
```

When I login it produces the error.

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found
```

Which is aimed at the line which I have pointed the arrow at.

Please what could be the reason for the error and how can I correct it.

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user

Comment: @sta thanks, Really appreciate it. Although Aken already provided the answer with full explanation but I am still very grateful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When referencing class names in PHP, they all act as **relative**, meaning class names will be appended to whatever the current namespace is.

If you are not in a namespace, and you look for the class `Auth`, PHP will attempt to find the fully-qualified class name (namespace + class) of `Auth`. If you are in the namespace `App` and you look for the class `Auth`, PHP will attempt to find `App\Auth`, or the `Auth` class defined inside the `App` namespace.

Because your controller is inside the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`, it is looking inside this same namespace for the class `Auth`.

In order to look for a *different* namespace, via an **absolute** look up, you can either prepend the class with a `\` backslash (start from the root), or add a `use` import statement.

Following [the example in Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user), adding a `use` statement for the appropriate facade should resolve your error:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

This can be placed along with the other `use` import statements in your class. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I would try that and reply you. Appreciate it

Comment: I feel like flying you to the international space station for a view of the earth. Thanks very much

Comment: >< That would be pretty cool! You're welcome :)

Comment: The shorthand of achieving that in the later version of laravel is simply calling the facade as  
                                                                                                                                    
 use Auth;